# OBIEE 12.2.1.2 - Dashboard Customizations - Dashboard Properties

Tags: properties, business-intelligence, prompt, dashboard, obiee

I want to know if there is another way than the dashboard properties window for activating the "hide" option in the latest OBIEE release.

I.e. like rearranging pages within dashboards using the catalog manager and not using the dashboard properties window.

Ideas and suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through the GUI? No. You can do it directly in the XML which is stored in the file system but that's not a supported way of doing it.

Comment: Hi Christian, that is what I have expected. XML works fine.